# How to clear session storage when browser tab close in Angular?

Tags: angular

When I use **browser history** its getting **logged in**. When I enter the **URL in new tab** its getting **redirected to login page**. I already tried browser tab close events to clear session.

```js
// 1
@HostListener('window:unload', ['$event'])
// 2
@HostListener('window:beforeunload')
```

But its working tab close and page refresh. I need only for browser tab close. How to achieve it?

Comment: you could use the OnDestroy(https://angular.io/api/core/OnDestroy) Event, when the component is closing.

Comment: Please give any example..

Comment: Why do you want to clear session storage when the tab is closed? The session storage would clear itself when the browser is closed anyways

Comment: Yes. but when I click browser history its getting loggedin with sessionstorage.

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement the OnDestroy interface like this

```
@Component({selector: 'your-cool-comp', template: `...`})
class MyComponent implements OnDestroy {
  ngOnDestroy() {
    // your logic to clean up session
  }
}
```

Comment: `export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
   sessionStorage.clear();
  } }`     is not working

Comment: Thanks. I have implemented in app.component.ts. when the browser tab close is not trigger. can you help me.

Comment: are the session relevant data stored in sessionstorage and not localstorage ?

Comment: Yes..  I use session storage. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

you write this code on your click event or destroy event

`if(windows.sessionStorage){
  sessionStorage.clear();
}`

Comment: Thanks, It calls the function when I close the browser but when i refresh the page it calls function too

Comment: you have to create common method for e.g clearSessionData(), and you write above code in that method this method you call on ngOninit() method.

Comment: `ngOnInit() {
    this.clearSessionData();
  }

  clearSessionData() {
    if (window.sessionStorage) {
      sessionStorage.clear();
    }
  }` Its work on page refresh too

Comment: I need browser tab close only. any idea?

Comment: Yes. but when I click browser history its getting loggedin with session.

Comment: use OnDestroy method and call this.clearSessionData(); in this method

Comment: OnDestroy is not triggered when browser close tab.

Comment: when you open your new tab then firstly call constructor and after ngOninit() you right clear session code in this two and after that you store new session...

Comment: import { Component, HostListener } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl:"./app/app.component.html"
})

export class AppComponent {
    @HostListener("window:onbeforeunload",["$event"])
    clearsessionStorage(event){
        sessionStorage.clear();
    }
}

Comment: in this code one method onbeforeunload which is called when browser close and clear your session data

Comment: Thanks. but its calling when page refresh also.. It's not working